# Get csv values to add up

Tags: c#, web-services, math

I have created a new integer called int VactualSum = 0;

I need VactualSum to equal the sum of all the values in an object called singleSummary[i].actual. then display the results in a text box called actualsumsent.
singleSummary[i].actual has 4 numeric values that I want my result to be the total of them when added up. e.g 10,20,30,40 the actualsumsent text box should show the value 100.

```
{ int VactualSum = 0;
```

I thought maybe having -

```
Vactual = Vactual + function[i].actual;
```

Then to put it in the text box have -

```
actualsumsent.Text = System.Convert.ToString(returned.Vactual)
```

But this does not work, the section in the array I am trying to add up is -

```
function[i].account = el.Descendants("var").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "account").SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value;
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: We don't have anywhere enough information to help you.  Watch it in the debugger.

Comment: Would you like to share what doesn't work means? That way, we could try and help. Also, shouldn't the last line be shortened to `actualsumsent.Text = returned.Vactual.ToString();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `singleSummary` is an array (or `IList<T>`) then you can do:

```
actualsumsent.Text = singleSummary.Sum(s => s.actual).ToString();
```

EDIT: Looking at the edit to the question, it seems you want to sum a comma-separated string containing int values. In that case you can calculate the sum like this:

```
int sum = singleSummary[i].account.Split(",").Select(s => int.Parse(s)).Sum();
```

Note this will throw an exception if the string is not well-formed.

Comment: so I dont need to bother witht the VactualSum?

Comment: @Lambo - If `singleSummary` is a collection of objects with a numeric property/field called `actual` then no you don't need the accumulator. This code does require .net 3.5 or later though.

Comment: singleSummary is an array of objects however when I put in the line you stated it does not give me the option for singleSummary which is odd?

Comment: @Lambo - You need to add a `using System.Linq` directive to the top of the file.

Comment: I have done that, but for some reason it is not allowing the single summary to be selected, the part of the array I am trying to access is singleSummary[i].account = el.Descendants("var").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "account").SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value;      does that help any? Because it is not recognising singleSummary :(

Comment: yes that is what I want, however where would I add this line? just after my array? I need the actual value to send to the web service, but need the form to generate the sum of them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something?   Do you simply want to sum your values and place them into your text box?  If you're using 3.5 or newer, you can use the following:

```
 actualsumset.Text = singleSummary.Sum(q=>q.actual).ToString();
```

Otherwise, you could sum your array up the classic way:

```
int VactualSum = 0;
foreach(YourObject obj in singleSummary)
{
   VactualSum+=obj.actual;
}
actualsumset.Text = VactualSum;
```

Comment: YourObject is the object type (which we don't know) which you have stored in your array of singleSummary.

Answer (score 0):

Is a Vactual a bit like a vacuole? Or is it like an actualValue?

Comment: VactualSum is a new integer that is to equal the sum of all the values in singleSummary.actual I cant get it to work though

Answer (score 0):

Sum of Comma separate values as a input

public int getSum(String inputNumbersCSV)
        {
            String[] inputNumbers = inputNumbersCSV.Split(',');
            int sumOfNum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < inputNumbers.Length; i++)
            {
                sumOfNum = sumOfNum + int.Parse(inputNumbers[i]); 
            }
            return sumOfNum;
        }